# How to request multiple addresses using wso2 ei

Tags: wso2

1. Request an address A
2. Get the result of A
3. use A result request address B
4. return B result

Comment: Are you talking about a service chain?

Comment: yes,I look up to use 'clone mediator' ,Right?

Answer (score 0):

use call mediator,You can then see the request result with the same sequence
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y45UH.png)